# Webpage using appScript: innerHTML assignment not working

Tags: css, materialize, innerhtml

I have a simple WebApp application that reads the data  from google sheet and displays in HTML using materialize css( 1.0.0), JS.  I am new to this stack of tools. HTML page has 2 containers and bottom one supposed to be populated (using innerHTML assignment)based on the selection on the top container.   The bottom container content is simple card contents in table format. I want to put a HTML Select object with List of values to be displayed and created a Appscript function. I am assigning the function output to innerHTML like this.
-- JS

```js
  function generateCards(text_card){
      document.getElementById("container-id").innerHTML += text_card;
  }

      function createAuthorCards(authorName) {
      document.getElementById("container-id").innerHTML = "";
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateCards).getCardDynamicText(authorName) ;

    }
```

--
If put copy/paste the function output in HTML it works( goes through rendering when refereshing), but if i use InnerHTML, the listbox is disabled, but all else seems ok.  [needed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O94EQ.jpg)please see the 2 attachments  needed and missing_listbox images.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beoOV.jpg)   Is there any limitations of using innerHTML in webApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using google Webapp. It looks google doesn't allow the editing of  dynamically created items. So I ended up using Modals to make the selections and save it.